# How can I use a file to read and write across multiple files in C++?

Tags: c++

I have given a sample of small program.

sum.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <fstream>

// I wanted to use these files across sum.cpp & main.cpp
std::ofstream out("out.txt");
std::ifstream in("in.txt");

int sum(int, int);
```

sum.cpp

```
#include "sum.hpp"

int sum(int one, int two) {
  out << "Called!";
  return one + two;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "sum.hpp"
int main() {
  int num_one, num_two;
  in>>num_one>>num_two;
  out<<sum(num_one, num_two);
}
```

[Generated error image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FocHn.png)

Error is about creating multiple out(ofstream) and in(ifstream) instances. I am not able to configure how to avoid this.

Comment: Could you please include the error as text, not an image? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: include `sum.hpp` in main instead of `sum.cpp`

Comment: `<filesystem>` is probably what you'll want.